# Allow for ENUM to be UPPER_CASE with ESLint naming-convention rule

Tags: eslint

I've just integrated ESLint into my application and it's been doing pretty well, except for the error:

> Enum Member name `CREATE` must match one of the following formats: camelCase

I've looked around and there's some discussion what the format for an emun *should* be, but I've always used `UPPER_CASE` so I'll stick to that.

In my `eslintrc` I have the `naming-convention` rule defined:

`"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",`

How would I create an exception for the usage of an enum?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md

```
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
    "error",
    {
      "selector": "enumMember",
      "format": ["UPPER_CASE"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```